# Is there a simple way to monitor how many megabytes are written on my SSD per day?

Tags: ssd

Since I got a new ssd and the limit of TBW is 100, I just want to predict how long it will last considering my day by day usage. Each day I do the same staff with my pc, so I just need to monitor for let's assume one week how many gigabytes I write on my ssd.
Is there a simple software that release kind of benchmark for each day or session?
Thanks.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

SSDs use an internal counter that is submitted via SMART data. Run the tool called [CrystalDiskInfo](https://osdn.net/projects/crystaldiskinfo/releases/) and look at the value `Total Host Writes`:

[image]

After 1 week run it again and compare the new value to the old value. Now you see how many data you write in 1 week.

Comment: It’s noteworthy that not all SSDs have this SMART attribute. Especially older ones (e.g. Crucial m4) are missing it.

Comment: @DanielB ok, my SSDs always had the attribute. Good to know this and keep in mind.

Comment: I'm missing this parameter. And several people in this thread are too: https://forum.lowyat.net/topic/4690493/all

Comment: @SUM1 which SSD do you use?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Kingston A400 240 GB (SA400S37/240G)

Comment: @SUM1 check the SSD with Kingston SSD Manager for firmware update and if it shows the SMART data.

Answer (score 0):

Some vendor tools like Samsung Magician will report the total bytes written for Samsung SSDs ... you can check that at the same time every day and note down the results.  Please note, different vendors will vary in the data reported.  If you use a Windows Performance Monitor or Sysinternals tool, you will get a too-low value.  Depending on how full your drive is and how frequently rewritten your data is, a write from the OS may result in multiple rewrites on the SSD.